# Scanf keeps looping

Tags: c

Well i have this code to find the paint quality of a room.

```
void get_room_size(char room_id, int * length, int * width) {
    while (*length <= 0 && *width <= 0) {
        printf("Enter length and width of room %c in feet: ", room_id);
        if (scanf("%d,%d", length, width)) {
            if (*length <= 0) {
                printf("###Error! Length must be a positive value!\n");
            }
            if (*width <= 0) {
                printf("###Error! Width must be a positive value!\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("bad data");
            *length = 0;
            *width = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if i enter

> a,1

It will go crazy and keep looping. Whats the problem?

Comment: You have no code that can read the 'a', so it never gets read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's going "crazy" is as follows. When `scanf` *fails* to read in `a` as a number (because it's not numeric, obviously), it *won't* advance the file pointer.

This is one reason why you shouldn't generally use `scanf` operations, a failure can leave the file pointer in an indeterminate position (such as if you only scan in 3 of 12 items).

> The other reason is that `scanf` means "scan formatted" and you would be hard pressed finding anything more *unformatted* than user input.

Anyway, back to the failure. Because the file pointer isn't advanced, the next time you come back to do `fscanf`, it will try to read that `a` *again* (and again and again).

If you want a decent function for handling user input, look no further than here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

This will input a line from the user, with overflow protection (unlike `gets` or `scanf` with unbounded `"%s"`).

It also flushes to end of line if the input was too long, which will stop the remainder of the line from affecting the next input operation.

You can then `sscanf` the buffer to your heart's content without any concerns re the file pointer.

The following test program shows how to use this:

```
int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

---

As an aside, you may want to re-examine your logic for a valid sized room. What you currently have would allow a room to be entered as 7 by -42 feet :-)

It's also not usually good form to rely on the output values being set to specific values on entry. If length and width are (for example) 3 and 4 on entry, this function will exit straight away without asking the user for input.

The first problem can be fixed by using `||` instead of `&&`. The second by initialising the variables to 0 at the start of the function so that the loop is entered.

---

For completeness, if you combine that original snippet above (the `include` statements and the `getLine()` function) with the following slightly modified `get_room_size()` function:

```
static void get_room_size(char room_id, int * length, int * width) {
    char buff[100];
    *length = *width = 0;
    while ((*length <= 0) || (*width <= 0)) {
        printf("Enter length and width of room %c in feet: ", room_id);
        int rc = getLine (NULL, buff, sizeof (buff));

        if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
            printf ("\nEnd of file encountered.\n");
            return;
        }

        if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
            printf ("\nInput too long, please retry.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (sscanf(buff, "%d,%d", length, width) != 2) {
            *length = *width = 0;
            printf ("\nInput not in desired form (<number>,<number>), "
                "please retry.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if ((*length <=0) || (*width <= 0)) {
            *length = *width = 0;
            printf ("\nBoth length and width must be greater than zero, "
                "please retry.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and the very simple test `main()`, you'll see a complete program showing how to do it.

```
int main (void) {
    int len, wid;
    get_room_size ('x', &len, &wid);
    printf ("Length is %d, width is %d.\n", len, wid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read a string, then try to parse it as an int.

Answer (score 0):

your scanf is taking in two integer. A is a character, think you want to
scanf("%c",  *room_id);
scanf("%d", length);

I reccommend you do them separately

Comment: I suspect the room ID is already known since it's passed in ( and _not_ as a pointer that could be changed and passed back) and it's used in the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
       if (scanf("%d,%d", length, width) == 2) {
            if (*length <= 0) {
                printf("###Error! Length must be a positive value!\n");
            }
            if (*width <= 0) {
                printf("###Error! Width must be a positive value!\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("bad data");
            *length = -1;
            *width = -1;
        }
```

Comment: That will still loop on `a,1` since it's not advancing the file pointer any more than the original code.

Answer (score -1):

You dont put & in `scanf()` statement so how its read

```
if (scanf("%d,%d", &length, &width))
```

Comment: Try this dude its mistake in your scanf() syntax.

Comment: This is not the problem... scanf already points to length & width.